# Java How to set new coordinates to a geometry in 2D

Tags: java, geometry, ogc

I have some geometry in 3D and I woudlike to return a geometry in 2D (dimension 2) with new coordinates :

```
private static Geometry convert2D(Geometry g3D) {
        // copy geometry
        Geometry g2D = (Geometry) g3D.clone();
        Geometry geometry;
        // set new 2D coordinates
        for (Coordinate c : g2D.getCoordinates()) {
            c.setCoordinate(new Coordinate(c.x, c.y));
        }

        // SET NEW COORDINATES TO g2D 
        
        return g2D;
    }
```

How can I do that with because the object geometry don't have the method `setCoordinates` ?